# how to add a Column using IF_ELSE

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe using add_column and if_else but I can get it I don't know how to do a correct logical test using logical conditional (or "|").

I have this kind data:

```
dataframe1
    variable 1  variable2   variable3
    (char)      (char)      (char)
    value       value       value
    value       value       value
    value       value       value
```

I try this:

```
dataframe2 <- dataframe1%>%
  add_column(newcolumn_name = if_else(variable3== "value1"|"value2”, TRUE, FALSE)
```

And I get this error:

> Unknown or uninitialised column: `value1`.Error in variable3 ==
> “value1“| "value2" :    operations are possible only for numeric,
> logical or complex types

Comment: `newvar = if_else(variable3 %in% c("value1","value2"), TRUE, FALSE)`, or much more succinctly, `newvar = (variable3 %in% c("value1","value2"))`.

Comment: good point ... I was focused on the misunderstanding of R syntax, I left the rest of it to your answer, @akrun

Comment: (@akrun, I've never understood the motivation or impetus to use `add_column`, frankly, but perhaps I'm missing its magic.)

Comment: @german-loyola -- just to clarify, are you trying to set `newcolumn_name` to `TRUE` if `variable3` equals `value1` or `value2`, or if `variable3` equals either of the corresponding cells in `variable1` or `variable2`?

Comment: @r2evans I think the reason may be related to adding columns at a specific location, but nowadays, `mutate` gained those functionality as well

Comment: @ngwalton  I'm trying to set newcolumn_name to TRUE if variable3 equals value1 or value2

Comment: @GermanLoyola Thanks, sorry for my confusion. The provided answers should get you there then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to extract the column with `.$`.  The `==` can be replaced with `%in%` and `|` is used mostly with regex pattern (`OR`) while `==` does a fixed match.  In addition, the output of `==` or `%in%` returns a logical vector.  So, we don't need the `if_else/ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
dataframe1 %>% 
    add_column(newcolumn_name = .$variable3 %in% c("value1", "value2"))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
head(mtcars) %>% 
    add_column(new_column_name = .$carb %in% c(1, 4))
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_column_name
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4            TRUE
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4            TRUE
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1            TRUE
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1            TRUE
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2           FALSE
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1            TRUE
```

---

Also, this can be done within `dplyr` itself i.e. using `mutate` and thus we don't need to extract the column

```
head(mtcars) %>%
    mutate(new_column_name = carb %in% c(1, 4))
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_column_name
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4            TRUE
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4            TRUE
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1            TRUE
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1            TRUE
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2           FALSE
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1            TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that with this code:

```
dataf2 <- dataf %>% 
  add_column(newcol = ifelse(dataf$var3=="value1" | dataf$var3=="value2", TRUE, FALSE) )
```

[image]